# How to fix timing of print statements when running Perl program under Cygwin?

Tags: perl, cygwin

The first Perl program I wrote was a little routine (below) to play with Bayes's Theorem.  It works on Windows 8 in the cmd window and also on Linux but I recently installed Cygwin on the Win8 machine and the behavior in cygwin is odd.  When I run it no print message appears but if I enter three numbers each followed by "enter" it responds with all three prints as well as the printf.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "What was the previous estimate that the hypothesis is true?\n";
my $x =  <STDIN>;
chomp $x;
$x *= .01;
print "What is the probability of the event if the hypothesis is true?\n";
my $y = <STDIN>;
chomp ($y);
$y *= .01;
print "What is the probability of the event if the hypothesis is false?\n";
my $z = <STDIN>;
chomp ($z);
$z *= .01;
my $bayes = 100 * ($x * $y) / (($x * $y) + $z * (1 - $x));
printf "Posterior probability is %3.2f%%\n", $bayes;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a buffering problem.  Set stdout to unbuffered:

```
$| = 1
```

Also, if you're running cygwin in a CMD window there may be some interaction between cygwin and CMD interfering as well. Try running in a mintty window.

Comment: The problem is with the Cygwin installation.  I made your change and now get a different error:

Comment: I'm running Cygwin's own shell. The problem is likely with the Cygwin installation.  I made your change and now get an error message saying cygssp-0.dll not found. There's a lot of information regarding that error available on the net so I should be able to find a solution.

Comment: In that case I'd completely remove and reinstall Cygwin.  It doesn't take that long assuming you have a reasonably fast Internet connection.

Comment: Normally (at least on sane Unix systems) stdout is automatically flushed when reading from stdin. So usually `$|=1` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Doing a reinstallation and selecting all Perl options fixed the problem.  I hadn't realized the default installation skips dozens of modules.  Once done, it didn't need the $|=1 to work.